# How do I set up the brightnes control on a Toshiba Satellite L650?

Tags: brightness

After upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 I have lost control of brightness of my Toshiba Satellite L650. Under Ubuntu 11.10 all worked ok.

Now I can change brightness only in terminal using:

```
echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

I have also folder named /sys/class/backlight/toshiba/ and in it there is file *brightness*

When I use my keyboard shortcut Fn-F6 and Fn-F7 value in file *brightness* (from toshiba folder) changes, but brightness in computer not, because it seems to be controlled by value in /acpi_video0/ folder.

I tried to change configuration in grub from this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

But then folder /toshiba/ disappeared, and I can not change brightness even in terminal.

acpi is installed.

Could anyone help me to find solution?

`lspci` gives following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Comment: Strange issue . Have a look [here](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight)

Comment: What if you link `/sys/class/backlight/toshiba/brightness` to `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`? I am not entirely sure if it's going to work, but there is not harm in trying. Remove the `acpi_backligh` option from Grub first, then reboot, an then run `sudo ln -sf /sys/class/backlight/toshiba/brightness /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. Now try the brightness keys. If it works, we can automate the linkage.

Comment: As I said I solved this issue by editing xorg.conf.
But thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer so other people with this laptop can benefit? Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro I've removed the answer from question and posted it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer OP posted in the [question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/168064/2):

I've just found solution and brightness started to work.

I just change put:

```
gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and my xorg.conf was very short:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection
```

So added at the end:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "ATI Radeon HD 5000M"
    Driver         "radeon"
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

And now is ok.